# Dart's DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch function retuns same incorrect value for any timestamp value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Here is my function to parse and format timestamp:

```dart
static String parseDate(int time) {
    var parsed = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time, isUtc: true);

    print(time);

    print(parsed.toString());

    var formatted = DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(parsed).toString();

    print(formatted);

    return formatted;
}
```

No matter what timestamp I use `DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch()` is returning same value i.e. `"1970-01-19 13:31:10.520Z"`.

console output of the function:

[image: console output of the function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function expects input parameter to be milliseconds since epoch, but your output suggests it is seconds rather than milliseconds.

Your input time:

`1603869517`

If I run

```dart
DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

`1603893810230`

If i run your function on my millis result is:

`1603879380000`

Which is exactly what your function should do.

My code:

```dart
var parsed = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time, isUtc: true);
var dateFormat = DateFormat.yMd().add_jm();
var formatted = dateFormat.format(parsed).toString();
print(dateFormat.parse(formatted).millisecondsSinceEpoch);
print(time);
return formatted;
```

Comment: I didn't know I was getting time in seconds. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, since your formatter doesn't save seconds, you could just multiply input by 1000.

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing.